# What is this grit/sand like build up on the piping under my bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, pvc

Under one sink in particular I have this brown sand/grit like build up, but cannot tell what it is? We are in a hard-water area but have a water softener. This is in the UK if it makes any difference.

[image: Brown Buildup on PCV Pipe]

Comment: My first guess would be a dirty calcium deposit.

Comment: Some of that looks like poorly applied plumbers putty, but there's a significant amount that looks like it's mineral buildup from a leak, like everyone else says.

Comment: New tail piece and probably new trap. So that you don't start with a coupling coming off the strainer. Or on the 1% off chance; run hot water for a while and then try to turn it a little to stop the leak.

Comment: And put some teflon tape on the screw thread for better sealing.

Answer (score 8):

It appears from the photo that the drain is leaking, albeit slowly, and what you are seeing are mineral deposits from your water.

Comment: The water softener is a distraction.  Fix the leak.  Why do you have two plastic nuts in such close proximity?  It might be hard to tighten those properly because you can't grip the tiny stub in between.  You should be able to put a simpler arrangement of piping there.  Clean up the threads on the basket and use a metal nut and a rubber washer to join it to the flange of a long enough tail piece without an added stub like you have.

Comment: It's a drain so it could be soap scum, grease, or other nastiness.  I once cleaned out an old drain really well to find that all the crud in it was plugging the holes a previous owner made with drain-o.  Ditto on 'fix the leak'.

Answer (score 6):

As for the practical question of "what should I do", I agree with the already proposed "fix the leak".

For the slightly more academic question of "what is this", here's my 2 ct:

From the photo, it looks like calcium or magnesium carbonates, meaning there would be some amount of mineral content that is escaping your water softening measures and depositing here from small amounts of leaking water.

If you soften the incoming water, that also has the side effect of making it more able to dissolve minerals downstream, so if your pipes did already contain mineral deposits from harder water running through in the past, they might now be remobilised by the softer water.

You could try some simple tests, like applying vinegar or citric acid to a sample of the substance and see if it dissolves, indicating calcium carbonates.

Comment: Might also be sodium compounds, given the softener. In any case, fixing the leak is the thing that needs doing, here.